# Write a user defined fillna function in pandas dataframe to fill np.nan different values with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-defined-functions, nan

Considering the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

change = [0.475, 0.625, 0.1, 0.2, -0.1, -0.75, 0.1, -0.1, 0.2, -0.2]
position = [1.0, 1.0, nan, nan, nan, -1.0, nan, nan, nan, nan]
date = ['20150101', '20150102', '20150103', '20150104', '20150105', '20150106', '20150107', '20150108', '20150109', '20150110']
pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'position': position, 'change': change})
```

Outputs

```
     date        change       position    
    20150101      0.475          1
    20150102      0.625          1
    20150103      0.1            np.nan
    20150104      0.2            np.nan
    20150105      -0.1           np.nan
    20150106      -0.75          -1
    20150107      0.1            np.nan
    20150108      -0.1           np.nan
    20150109      0.2            np.nan
    20150110      -0.2           np.nan
```

I want to fillna with the following rules:

1. For rows whose "position" value is np.nan, if value of "change" has the same sign of last non-null value of position (change * position>0, such as 0.1*1 and 0.2*1 >0), we fillna with last non-null value.
2. For rows whose "position" value is np.nan, if value of "change" has the same sign of last non-null value value of position (change * position <=0 such as -1*0.1), we fillna with 0.
3. Once one np.nan is filled with 0, the following np.nan will be filled with 0 as well.

The following are the expected results from the sample data frame:

```
     date        change       position    
    20150101      0.475          1
    20150102      0.625          1
    20150103      0.1            1
    20150104      0.2            1
    20150105      -0.1           0
    20150106      -0.75          -1
    20150107      0.1            0
    20150108      -0.1           0
    20150109      0.2            0
    20150110      -0.2           0
```

EDIT:

The method I developed is the following:

```
while(any(np.isnan(x['position']))):
    conditions = [(np.isnan(x['position'])) & (x['position'].shift(1) * x['change'] > 0),
                  (np.isnan(x['position'])) & (x['position'].shift(1) * x['change'] <= 0)]
    choices = [x['position'].shift(1), 0]
    x['position'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=x['position'])
```

but as you can see, it is not very satisfying, and very slow if you have a 80,000,000 rows of data.

Any suggestions? thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what you have tried?

Comment: just added things I tried, thanks

Comment: @ JohnE, just edited as you suggested, thank you. My solution doesn't work on large dataframe, so I am still looking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is pretty solid, the main issue is you are iterating through it more times than you need to.  `shift()` only goes back one line at a time, but if you change that to `fillna(method='ffill')` then you essentially get an unlimitied number of shifts but only have to do this one time instead of with multiple iterations (how many iterations will depend on your data).

```
conditions = [
    (np.isnan(x['position'])) & (x['position'].fillna(method='ffill')*x['change']>0),
    (np.isnan(x['position'])) & (x['position'].fillna(method='ffill')*x['change']<=0)]
```

But I believe you can go one step further and eliminate the `while` by adding another `fillna` at the end:

```
conditions = [
    (np.isnan(x['position'])) & (x['position'].fillna(method='ffill')*x['change']>0),
    (np.isnan(x['position'])) & (x['position'].fillna(method='ffill')*x['change']<=0)]

choices=[x['position'].shift(1),0]
x['position'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=x['position'])

x['position'] = x['position'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

On your sample data, the first change is about 2x faster than your code, and the second is about 4x.  I get the same answers as you, but of course you'll want to verify this on the real data to be sure.

Comment: Haha, not really magic just minimizing the number of iterations.  Your code there was really quite good, it's just that it is always possible to make it a little better...